# When I use drawText in canvas in jetpack-compose and set the textStyle, the position is out of center

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

```
drawText(
            textMeasurer = textPercentMeasure,
            text = textPercent,
            topLeft = Offset(
                canvasWidth / 2 - textPercentWidth / 2,
                canvasHeight / 2 - textPercentHeight - space
            ),
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        )
```

When not setting the style, my text is exactly centered. After setting this style, the text shifts to the right

Comment: What about textPercentMeasure,textPercentWidth and textPercentHeight?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Compose, but maybe the problem is the text getting measured *before* you change its size? So your offset is half the *original* size, not the *current* size. If that's what's happening and you're making the text bigger, it'll end up too far to the right (larger text needs to be offset more to the left, to keep its centre in the right place)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have found a solution to the problem

Comment: @有朋自远方来 please mark solution as accepted, or provide an answer that solves your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply the same style to the draw and to measure the size of the text.

Something like:

```
val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
Canvas(Modifier.fillMaxSize()){

    val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult =
        textMeasurer.measure(
            text = AnnotatedString("Extremely high"),
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        )
    val textSize = textLayoutResult.size

    drawText(
        textLayoutResult = textLayoutResult,
        topLeft = Offset(
            x  = size.width/2 - textSize.width/2f,
            y = size.height/2 - textSize.height/2f
        ),
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. You solved my question.Thank you